# Admin grid columns change after mass action or page switch - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, layout, grid, coupon, adminhtml

**Problem:** 
My new columns to Coupon grid disappear after AJAX pagination or delete calls.

**My goal**:
I want to extend Coupons grid in Shopping Cart Rule edit page by adding some columns.

**How to:**
If you create a shopping cart rule and set "Autogenerate coupons" checkbox to true and save, you will be able to go to Manage Coupons tab afterwards and generate coupons from there for this rule.

My magento store is using coupons that can be used **only once**, so I need to save a record on **when** a particular coupon has been used. As magento coupons didn't have that attribute, I added a column `date_used` in `salesrule_coupon` table using install script:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
  ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('salesrule_coupon')} ADD date_used DATE NULL after created_at;
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

**date_used** is created and I am able to see it in database. Next in order to add a new column to coupons grid I do the following:

1. I extend the Grid block class at `code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Coupons/Grid.php` and create my own `code/local/Company/Coupons/Block/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Coupons/Grid.php`

Here is the code:

```
<?php

class Company_Coupons_Block_Adminhtml_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Coupons_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Coupons_Grid {
    protected function _prepareColumns() {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        // adding a column with date_used index
        $this->addColumn('date_used', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Date Used'),
            'index'  => 'date_used',
            'width'  => '50',
            'type'   => 'date',
        ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

2. Create a layout file coupons.xml and place it in design `design/adminhtml/company/default/layout/coupons.xml`. In this layout I am adding my own coupongrid block as `company_coupons/adminhtml_promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid` and removing magento's `promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid`. As you can see, everything happens inside `adminhtml_promo_quote_edit` block.

Layout file:

```
<!-- adding own grid block and removing magento core grid from this block-->
<layout>
    <adminhtml_promo_quote_edit>
        <reference name="promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons">
            <block type="company_coupons/adminhtml_promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid" name="coupongrid" after="promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid"/>
            <remove name="promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_promo_quote_edit>
</layout>
```

3. Finally, I register these changes in my `etc/config.xml` file.

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Coupons>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </Company_Coupons>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <company_coupons>
                <class>Company_Coupons_Helper</class>
            </company_coupons>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <company_coupons>
                <class>Company_Coupons_Block</class>
            </company_coupons>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <company_coupons>
                <class>Company_Coupons_Model</class>
            </company_coupons>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <coupons_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Coupons</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </coupons_setup>
            <coupons_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </coupons_write>
            <coupons_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </coupons_read>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <coupons>
                        <class>company_coupons/observer</class>
                        <method>saveCouponUsageInfo</method>
                    </coupons>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <coupons>
                    <file>coupons.xml</file>
                </coupons>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

4. I also added `saveCouponUsageInfo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)` method in `Model/Observer.php`, but I won't include that as it works just fine.

---

My solution works and I can clearly see the new column in my grid:
[image: Coupon grid in Rule Edit page, Manage Coupons tab]

**BUT!** If I do ajax operations, like request the second page of grid, or mass delete, my column just disappears and grid contains its old set of columns. Of course, if I reload the entire page, `date_used` column comes back to grid. See below *(image is cropped, 20 coupons are present on page 2):*

[image]

---

I used the debugger in PhpStorm and noticed that coupon grid html, after mass delete, is requested by:

```
/index.php/admin/promo_quote/couponsGrid/id/64/key/1eccc1c40033fa8bf64007738a22dc1a?ajax=true&isAjax=true
```

Same request used for pagination, but adding page number into URL:

```
/index.php/admin/promo_quote/couponsGrid/id/64/key/1eccc1c40033fa8bf64007738a22dc1a/page/2/?ajax=true&isAjax=true
```

As you probably have guessed from URL, during those calls `couponsGridAction()` method in `Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController` is triggered. The problem is that my implementation of `_prepareColumns()` is never called, as debugger revealed. Thus `date_used` column isn't included anymore.

Anyone faced this problem before? I spent an entire day on this little bug and would be extremely grateful for any hint or guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the controller action executed, i.e. `Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController::couponsGridAction()` you'll see that it does the usual `$this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();`, which means that there is a layout defined for this AJAX action.
Open `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/promo.xml` and at the bottom you'll see the layout defined for this particular action:

```
    <adminhtml_promo_quote_couponsgrid>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="adminhtml/promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid" name="promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid" />
        </block>
    </adminhtml_promo_quote_couponsgrid>
```

So you need to define a handle for this action in your layout coupons.xml file, something like this:

```
    <adminhtml_promo_quote_couponsgrid>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="company_coupons/adminhtml_promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid" name="promo_quote_edit_tab_coupons_grid" />
        </block>
    </adminhtml_promo_quote_couponsgrid>
```

As you can see, I simply changed `adminhtml` with `company_coupons` in the block's type declaration and updated the path to your module's class, and it actually work (as your question was very well documented I actually could reproduce it here in local and this code is actually tested), as simple as that :)

Comment: The grid action is really hard to get since Magento tends to "hide" it by rendering it only via the controller and not using a layout for it.

That said, I would personally change totally the approach and use an event/observer to add the column to the grid, no ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be what do you mean by "hard to get"? In this case there is a layout handle defined for that particular action (i.e. the rendering of the grid for the ajax action), so the event/observer is not necessary, just a handle for this action in the OP's custom layout xml file

Comment: Indeed, for this one, they were kind enough. But they tend to do [those kind of structure](http://freegento.com/doc/db/d9d/class_mage___adminhtml___poll___answer_controller.html#b02d062cb6a150c8eeb9ed94de1fc83f) more than often in the admin. And regarding the event/observer, I tend to view it as less intrusive and less prone to conflicts with other modules / updates of the core. But that is maybe just a matter of taste and colours :)

Comment: @b.enoit.be if you're talking about the gridAction in the link you provided, it is actually almost the same: instead of using a layout file they render the block directly from the controller. I agree that consistency would be nice, but in the end, it's just a matter of reading the code and understanding what it's doing. And I totally agree with you: event/observer is always the best approach, but in this case I taught it was better to stay in the same line as what the OP had done so far: let's keep it consistent when we can :)

Comment: @OSdave I totally forgot about the fact that controller actions have their designated layout elements. So couponsGridAction is mapped to adminhtml_promo_quote_couponsgrid layout element. I added this element into my coupons.xml and it worked like a charm. Thank you, man!

Comment: @OSdave just wait for 4-6 hours, seems like I can't award you those 50 points until 12 hours pass from bounty start.